# How to distinguish failed tests from syntax error in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have this `Jenkinsfile`:

```
node{
  stage ('Checkout')
  {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage ('Build')
  {
    try {
        sh '''
           mvn clean -B org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install
        '''
    } catch (err) {
        // do nothing
       currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
    } finally {
        //step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
       step([$class: 'XUnitBuilder', testTimeMargin: '3000', thresholdMode: 1,
    thresholds: [
        [$class: 'FailedThreshold',   unstableThreshold: '2'],
        [$class: 'SkippedThreshold',  unstableThreshold: '']],
    tools: [
        [$class: 'JUnitType', deleteOutputFiles: false, failIfNotNew: false, pattern: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml', skipNoTestFiles: true, stopProcessingIfError: false]]
    ])
    }
  }
}
```

I want to mark the build as `UNSTABLE` when : some tests are failed using threshold of xUnit plugin, and I want to mark it `FAILED` if there is any error in the code like syntax error.

The problem here is that `catch` is executed in both situations: code error and test failure. How can I configure the `Jenkinsfile` to make the difference ?

After running a build that has 3 test failures ( threshold is 2 ), I expected the build to be `UNSTABLE` but it turned to `FAILED`:

```
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing JUnit
[xUnit] [INFO] - [JUnit] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml' relative to '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins-failure_master-EHKMAGGDJWHA7FNGHQYY2VJNJHBX2RXI3XJY4NU5EB2PYT4ERTZQ' for the testing framework 'JUnit'.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Failed Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - The total number of tests for this category exceeds the specified 'unstable' threshold value.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Setting the build status to FAILURE
[xUnit] [INFO] - Stopping recording.
```

New case: I commented the line `currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'` and I added a syntax error in the test class. The build is successed even with the `COMPILATION ERROR` and it skipped the tests:

```
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing JUnit
[xUnit] [INFO] - [JUnit] - No test report file(s) were found with the pattern '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml' relative to '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins-failure_master-EHKMAGGDJWHA7FNGHQYY2VJNJHBX2RXI3XJY4NU5EB2PYT4ERTZQ' for the testing framework 'JUnit'.  Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  Did you generate the result report(s) for 'JUnit'?
[xUnit] [WARNING] - No test reports found for the metric 'JUnit' with the resolved pattern '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Skipping the metric tool processing.
[xUnit] [INFO] - There are errors when processing test results.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Skipping tests recording.
```

Comment: Just a quick comment, but it looks like your failed threshold is at '' = '0'. Could you try with '2', as set-up for 'unstable'?

Comment: @Luc the failed threshold doesn't have effect here. I'll update my code as I don't really need it.

Answer (score 2):

From [Reporting test results and storing artifacts](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Reporting-test-results-and-storing-artifacts) (declarative pipeline):

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker "java" }
    stages {
        stage("build") {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            archive "target/**/*"
            junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

Use `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` to prevent failing the build on test failures. The `junit` step then collects the test results and marks the build as unstable.

This is also how it is done under the covers when using a non-pipeline Maven job, see [JENKINS-24655](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24655).